# How can one implement twitter oauth2 on a single page application with a django backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, twitter, django-rest-framework

So i have a front end app in angular on one server and a Django app on another using rest

Now i want to have a user click on the signup using twitter button on the front end, but have the backend make the request to twitter with my twitter app credentials safe in the backend, and have the user redirected to the frontend on the same page they made the request at so it all seems like a seamless process

How do i implement this with Django, is there a library that already solves this problem, or is there a technique one can use to have the auth popup appear in the frontend whilst the request was made in the backend

any help is most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [django-twitter-oauth](https://github.com/henriklied/django-twitter-oauth) for twitter support, or [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) which has a lot of other services besides twitter.